# Can I set manually the seed of Randomization in Visual Basic Application

Tags: vb.net, random

I need to get the same sequence of the randomization by setting the seed.
Can I do this in Visual Basic?

Code, I used:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
   Dim rand As New Random
   MsgBox(rand.Next(1, 10))
End Sub
```

**Thanks and have a nice day!**

Comment: The Random class has an [overloaded Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor). -- You'd see it immediately using the standard syntax to declare a new object: `Dim rand As New Random()`. As you add the first parenthesis, Intellisense shows you the available Constructors. -- Not clear what's use of this seed, given the example you're providing.

Comment: "Before calling Rnd, use the Randomize statement without an argument to initialize the random-number generator with a seed based on the system timer."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.vbmath.rnd?view=net-5.0
So, i want to set the seed manually not by the system time, is this possible?

Comment: `Rnd` and  `Randomize` have nothing to do with the [.Net Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random) class. The former is there because of compat requirements, the latter is what you need to use.

Comment: AFAIAA in .net core the random class is no longer seeded from the timer, by the way

Comment: Okay, but is there any method to set manually the seed, from integer or string etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Jimi's led you all the way to the KoolAid lake.. Now you just need to take a drink!

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
   Dim rand As New Random(1) 'seed it with 1
   MsgBox(rand.Next(1, 10))
End Sub
```

Every time this app starts, the same number will be seen in the MsgBox. If you don't like 1, there are over 4 billion other numbers to choose from ;)

Comment: Sorry for that, thanks a lot to everyone
Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

From the documentation.

> You can generate the same sequence of random numbers by providing the
> same seed value to the Random(Int32) constructor.

For the example and detailed description refer below link, and search for "Retrieve the same sequence of random values".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-5.0